# ionic issue while swiping up/down the app but only in iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have an issue with iOS devices when using the ionic 3 framework. Whenever I swipe up/down the app an empty space appears bellow/above the app. I attach an image that shows the empty space at the bottom while swiping up. Similar is for swiping down. I don't have this issue in android devices. How can a disable it?

[image: App while swiping up]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using the property no-bounce in ion-content works

```
<ion-content no-bounce>
   html content
</ion-content>
```